# Make child Route fire model hook only after the promise returned by parent Route has resolved in EmberJs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, promise, ember-router

Given the following router, with a fairly straight forward routing synatx:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('foos', function(){
    this.resource('foo', { path: '/:foo_id' }, function(){
      this.route('bar');
    });
  });
});
```

I have `FoosController`, and `FooBarController`, with corresponding routes for each: `FoosRoute` and `FooBarRoute`.
Both routes have a `model` hook that returns a promise, which is obtained from `ic.ajax`.

When I navigate to `/foos`, and then navigate to `/foos/123/bar`, the following sequence happens:

- `FoosRoute#model` make XHR request to `GET /api/foos`
- Response returned from `/api/foos`
- `FooBarRoute#model` makes an XHR request to `GET /api/foos/123`
- Response returned from `/api/foos/123`

This is great, and my app works fine. Next I naigate directly to `/foos/123/bar`, the following sequence happens:

- `FoosRoute#model` make XHR request to `GET /api/foos`
- `FooBarRoute#model` makes an XHR request to `GET /api/foos/123`
- Response returned from `/api/foos/123`
- Response returned from `/api/foos`

The `model` hooks for both `FoosRoute` and `FooBarRoute` fire in quick succession.

The server takes a longer time to return the response from `/api/foos` than it does for  `/api/foos/123`, and so they arrive out of order. This puts my app into an incorrect state, and I would like to fix this, by ensuring that the `model` hook for `FooBarRoute` is fired only after the promise returned by the `model` hook for `FoosRoute` has resolved.

How can I do this?

---

These JsBins provide a concise demonstration of the problem, forked off the demo put together by @kingpin2k:

Using `find`. Both models load, but child route loads its model before parent route:

- http://jsbin.com/topot/3/edit?html,js,console,output

Using `fetch`. Both models load, and child route correctly waits for parent route to load model, but UI doesn't update:

- http://jsbin.com/topot/4/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Something like `RSVP.all([promise1,promise2]).then(function(){ /* this runs only when both promises resolved */ })` ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum is there a way that I can obtain a reference to the promise of the parent `Route`'s `model` hook, from the child `Route`'s `model` hook? If so, this could work.

Comment: I'm a little confused, this is how Ember is already built, a child route's model hook doesn't fire until the parent route's model is resolved.  Are you sure the parent route is returning a promise?  Here's an example where the child route depends on the parent's route model, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/333#/colors/1 and the model hook doesn't happen until the parent route's model is resolved.

Comment: Will you add your model hooks and mention any client side data libraries you might be using

Comment: @kingpin2k Thanks for the jsbin. Yup - all the routes in my app return promises in their `model` hooks. I am using `ember-model` in the `model` hooks, and within its adapters, I am using `ic-ajax` (which is the origin of the promises)

Comment: Are you using find or fetch with Ember model?  Sorry, I should be more specific, App.Model.find or App.Model.fetch in the model hook?

Comment: @kingpin2k I have tried both started off with `find`, now using `fetch` (as I understand it, `fetch` always returns a promise), does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: It should make a huge difference, find returns a model immediately, and then updates the model later when the results come down (this could be after the page has rendered).  fetch returns a promise, and it isn't resolved until the ajax call is returned.  Interestingly you said that ic-ajax was returning the promise, but that shouldn't be correct.  Ember model should be returning the promise you are using.

Comment: watch the console, http://jsbin.com/UXOtOJI/32/edit

Comment: @kingpin2k Thanks very much for the JsBins that you put together, they helped me to narrow down the problem further, and now I think it might be to do with the way ember, ember-model, and ic-ajax are "wired" together. I have not arrived at a solution yet, but I have put together a concise demo of the problem: http://jsbin.com/topot/3/edit?html,js,console,output and http://jsbin.com/topot/4/edit?html,js,console,output I have updated the question and there is some description in the JsBin as well. Much appreciated if you could help me figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fetch` as we already discussed, and in your custom `find` overload you need to return the record, not the results of `record.load` which is undefined.

```
return App.AppModel.fetch(1);

App.AppModel.adapter = Ember.Adapter.create({
    find: function(record, id) {
        //instead of jQuery.ajax, use ic.ajax as suggested by stefanpenner
        //See: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4442#issuecomment-36207354
        var req = ic.ajax.raw({
            type: 'GET',
            url: App.apiUrl+'/appmodels/'+id,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false
        });
        return req.then(function resolve(result) {
          console.log('AppModel adapter find resolve', result.response);

          record.load(id, result.response);
          return record;
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/cukuciva/1/edit